# ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException

Tags: android, paypal

If I add paypal sdk then I get this problem else my project is running successfully.

Can some tell me from which dependency it is conflicting?

Here are my dependencies...

```
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

    compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.11.1.jar'
```

I removed build files and rebuilt the project but no hope and strange part is I have one dummy project where I write code first, in that project everything working fine but here getting error always.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal library includes GSON dependency and Retrofit too, you have to exclude the GSON dependency from retrofit.

Comment: I tried but then my Gson converter giving error. Even I tried every dependency but no solution.